# undefined function interp2fast_double

Tags: matlab, double, mex

I got another problem again in Matlab with ASM code, I need to call function `interp2fast_double.c` from matlab, but when I run it, it gave me error like this :

```
Undefined function 'interp2fast_double' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in interpfast (line 59)
    J = interp2fast_double(double(I),double(xi),double(yi),double(mode));

Error in ASM_getProfileAndDerivatives3D (line 33)
gt= interpfast(I,xi,yi,zi,'cubic')';
```

I searched the problem and in forum they said I must set the path, after I done that the error still there...

Can someone help me with this please...

Answer (score 0):

Have you compiled the c file into a mex file?

Setup you mex compiler

```
>> mex -setup
```

Choose the relevant compiler.

Then

```
>> mex -largeArrayDims -O interp2fast_double.c
```

Comment: yes, I used the setup compiler and choose the relevant compiler and it works :) 
thank you.